# Как сделать установщик программы через терминал Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, package, deb

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой: перемещение проекта на C++ на другие компьютеры занимает очень много времени и места при большом проекте. Погуглил как можно всё переместить одним файлом и наткнулся на установщики. Но не имею представления как вообще всё это делать без специальных программ кроме терминала на Linux mint 17.1

P.S. Имеются в виду программы устанавливающиеся на компьютер и появляющихся в меню

Comment: очень глобальный и потому неподходящий для данного сайта вопрос. [это по поводу меню](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/), а по поводу остального — задавайте, пожалуйста, более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Не совсем  понятно при чём тут меню, если нужно переносить проект. Чем, например, git не угодил?  Каким образом перемещение требует больше места, чем сам проект? Если же речь о собранном программном комплексе (но тогда при чём тут C++?), на то есть спецификации rpm и deb.

Comment: Почитайте руководство для начинающих в пакетировании, также имеет смысл разобраться с *git-buildpackage*. https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit